# Call link in mobile site not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my mobile site, I used `<a href="tel:+1800229933">Call us free!</a>`  for making a call to the specified number from the device.But its not working in most of the devices.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `callto:` for example: `<a href="callto:+1800229933">Call us free!</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend inserting the phone number in the international format: the plus sign (+), the country code, the local area code, and the local number. We do not really know where our visitors will be located. If they are in the same country, or even in the same local area, the international format will still work.
Call us free!

Comment: no need of international nums..as it is used by local .

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe the "+" is necessary. But I recommend trying this:

```
<a href="tel:1800229933" rel="external">Call us free!</a>
```